# convert UTF-8 to ANSI (windows-1252)

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iconv, windows-1252

I'm trying to save a string in hebrew to file, while having the file ANSI encoded.
All attemps failed I'm afraid.

1. The PHP file itself is UTF-8.

So here's the code I'm trying :

```
$to_file = "בדיקה אם נרשם";  
$to_file = mb_convert_encoding($to_file, "WINDOWS-1255", "UTF-8");  
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) ."/txt/TESTING.txt",$to_file);
```

This returns **false** for some reason.

Another attempt was :

```
$to_file = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1252", $to_file);
```

This returns an empty string. while this did not work, Changing the outpout charset to windows-1255 DID work. so the function itself works, But for some reason it does not convert to 1252.

I ran this function before and after the `iconv` and printed the results

`mb_detect_encoding ($to_file);`

before the `iconv` the encoding is UTF-8.
after the `iconv` the encoding is ASCII(??)

I'd really appreciate any help you can give

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is a *Latin* encoding; you cannot encode Hebrew characters in Windows-1252. That's why it doesn't work.
[Windows-1255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) is an encoding for Hebrew, that's why it works.

The reason it doesn't work with `mb_convert_encoding` is that [mb_ doesn't support Windows-1255](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).

*Detecting* encodings is by definition impossible. Windows-1255 is a single-byte encoding; it's virtually impossible to distinguish any one single byte encoding from another. The result is just as valid in ASCII as it is in Windows-1255 or Windows-1252 or ISO-8859 or any other single byte encoding.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more information.

Comment: I suspected as much, Some 3rd party vendor insists that I need to supply his software a hebrew text encoded with windows-1252, I guess I'm not crazy. 

Thanks alot for the amazing resource you just linked!

Comment: @Patrick - Well, the only way to do so is to transcript Hebrew texts in latin characters, just like you can write Arabic as "As-salamu alaykum" ;-)

Comment: @Patrick: the vendor has no clue. You can transliterate to Latin (like Alvaro said), or use some kind of escaping mechanism. But can't keep it as readable Hebrew text. Unless he said "text encoded as Windows ANSI." Because in the MS lingo "ANSI code page" means "current system code page", so the system can be changed to use Hebrew, and then it's possible to have Hebrew in an "ANSI code page" (but not 1252, definitely)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php
$heb = 'טקסט בעברית .. # ';
$utf = preg_replace("/([\xE0-\xFA])/e","chr(215).chr(ord(\${1})-80)",$heb);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($heb);
echo '<pre>';
echo '------';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($utf);
echo '<pre>';
?>
```

Output will be like this:

### ���� ������ .. #  <-- $heb - what we get when we print hebrew ANSI Windows 1255

טקסט בעברית .. #  <- $utf - The Converted ANSI Windows 1255 to now UTF ...:)

Comment: It looks like "Output will be like this: ���� ������ .. # טקסט בעברית .. # " for me. Please edit.

Comment: thats ok - I guess I was not clear..:) .  The code we are looking at has two values - one is our source  $heb which is in hebrew ANSI Windows 1255 when we try and print it we get : ���� ������  under UTF file... the next string that is printed is $utf, the converted string. I did not count the echo '<pre>' in my example..